# Change a href parameters by JS or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change a couple of href parameters using jQuery or plain JS.

```
<a href="market/pid=422&counturl=1&sizeurl=2" id="link2" target="_blank">Go!</a>
```

I tried

```
var x = "market/pid=422";
var counturl = "&counturl=1";
var sizeurl = "&sizeurl=2";
var result = x + counturl + sizeurl;
$('#link2').attr('href', result);

$('#size-m').on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
size = 1.5;
var sizeurl = "&sizeurl=1.5";
$('#link2').attr('href', result);
});

$('#size-l').on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
size = 2;
var sizeurl = "&sizeurl=2";
$('#link2').attr('href', result);
});

$('#countplus').on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
count = 2;
var counturl = "&counturl=2";
$('#link2').attr('href', result);
});

$('#countminus').on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
count = 1;
var counturl = "&counturl=1";
$('#link2').attr('href', result);
});
```

And when I click on #size-m I get

```
<a href="market/pid=422&counturl=1&sizeurl=1.5" id="link2" target="_blank">Go!</a>
```

Ok.
Than I click on #countplus

```
<a href="market/pid=422&counturl=2&sizeurl=2" id="link2" target="_blank">Go!</a>
```

The first click #size-m is overwritten(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your logic, try:

```js
function getLink(count, size) {
    return `market?pid=422&counturl=${count}&sizeurl=${size}`;
}

var count = 1;
var size = 2;

$('#size-m').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    size = 1.5;
    $('#link2').attr('href', getLink(count, size));
});

$('#size-l').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    size = 2;
    $('#link2').attr('href', getLink(count, size));
});

$('#countplus').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    count = 2;
    $('#link2').attr('href', getLink(count, size));
});

$('#countminus').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    count = 1;
    $('#link2').attr('href', getLink(count, size));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't change `result` variable in your events function, therefore the result that you are giving as a parameter to `attr` will be the same result that have been declared!